# Trying to create a 2D list but the first element of a row changes the last element of last row to the said element

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

This a part of my code:

```
int h = height+1;
int w = width+1;
char board[h][w];    
board[0][w] = 'a';
board[1][0] = '|';

printf("%c, %c", board[0][w], board[1][0]);
```

but when i compile and run it i get this:

```
|, |
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by accessing out-of-range of array. Allocate enough elements or use correct index.

former example:

```
int h = height+1;
int w = width+1;
char board[h][w+1]; /* allocate w+1 elements instead of w */
board[0][w] = 'a';
board[1][0] = '|';

printf("%c, %c", board[0][w], board[1][0]);
```

latter example:

```
int h = height+1;
int w = width+1;
char board[h][w];    
board[0][w-1] = 'a'; /* use w-1 instead of w */
board[1][0] = '|';

printf("%c, %c", board[0][w-1], board[1][0]); /* use w-1 instead of w */
```

Comment: Is it actually undefined behavior? Or would `board[0][w]` be the same location as `board[1][0]` in this case? This is not meant to be a separate question, but just a consideration on the answer.

Comment: @javey Yes, it is. Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) J.2 Undefined behavior: "An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6)."

Comment: that worked out well, thanks a lot. I am new to array and C programming.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
board[0][w-1] = 'a';
board[1][0] = '|';
```

Or,

```
board[0][width] = 'a';
board[1][0] = '|';
```